# type error with apex

Tags: apex, sosl

with a list of "mails", I want to search for emails in my salesforce object "PrincipalProduit__c", but I find errors in my variable "var and searchList"

```
public  List<String> getValo(){
List<String> mailList=getMail();
List<sObject> searchList = new List<sObject>();
List<String> var=new List<String>();
for(integer l=0;l<mailList.size();l++){
    searchList = [FIND :mailList[l] IN EMAIL FIELDS RETURNING PrincipalProduit__c(id)];   
    var.add((List<PrincipalProduit__c>)searchList[0]);
}
system.debug(var);
return var;
}
```

help me find the type I need to use to display my id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things you need to change in your code so that it returns the `List<PrincipalProduit__c>` or `List<String>`

- SOSL returns `List<List<sObject>>`, hence you should assign the returned results to a `List<List<sObject>>`'s instance.
- You are adding `List<PrincipalProduit__c>` to a `List<String>` whereas it should be added to `List<PrincipalProduit__c>`'s instance.
- As you will be adding `List<PrincipalProduit__c>` to a `list` i.e. `var`, you should be using the `addAll` method of `List` class.
- Return type of your method should be `List<PrincipalProduit__c>` instead of `List<String>` or else, you can loop through the `List<PrincipalProduit__c>` and get the required `string` and then add it to the `List` that needs to be returned.
- **You should avoid using any query in for loop, having queries in loop would lead you to hitting the governor limits. Hence, you will have to remove your `SOSL` query from `for loop` to avoid hitting the limits.**

A more optimized version of your method would be something like below, where `SOSL` has been removed from `for loop` and it will fetch all the needed records in one hit and it will return you `List<PrincipalProduit__c>`

```
public  List<PrincipalProduit__c> getValo(){
    List<String> mailList=getMail();
    List<List<sObject>> searchList = new List<List<sObject>>();
    List<PrincipalProduit__c> var=new List<PrincipalProduit__c>();

    string searchString = '';
    string finalSearchString = '';
    List<string> secondMailList = new List<String>();
    for(string mail : mailList){
        searchString = '("' + mail + '")';
        secondMailList.add(searchString);
    }
    finalSearchString = string.join(secondMailList,' OR ');
    searchList = [FIND :finalSearchString IN EMAIL FIELDS RETURNING PrincipalProduit__c(id)];   
    var.addAll((List<PrincipalProduit__c>)searchList[0]);

    system.debug(var);
    return var;
}
```

If you want your method to return `List<String>` instead of `List<PrincipalProduit__c>`, then your method should be

```
public  List<String> getValo(){
    List<String> mailList=getMail();
    List<List<sObject>> searchList = new List<List<sObject>>();
    List<String> var=new List<String>();

    string searchString = '';
    string finalSearchString = '';
    List<string> secondMailList = new List<String>();
    for(string mail : mailList){
        searchString = '("' + mail + '")';
        secondMailList.add(searchString);
    }
    finalSearchString = string.join(secondMailList,' OR ');
    searchList = [FIND :finalSearchString IN EMAIL FIELDS RETURNING PrincipalProduit__c(id)];   
    for(PrincipalProduit__c principalProd : (List<PrincipalProduit__c>)searchList[0]){
        var.add(principalProd.Id);
    }

    system.debug(var);
    return var;
}
```

You can get further help on SOSL at [this](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_database/apex_database_sosl) link. If you still want to use your existing method where you have `SOSL` in loop, then this is how it would look like.

**Note : Below method will hit the governor limits, if you have more than 20 email addresses in your mail list. You can find the governor limits of `SOSL` at [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm) link.**

This will return `List<PrincipalProduit__c>`

```
public  List<PrincipalProduit__c> getValo(){
    List<String> mailList=getMail();
    List<List<sObject>> searchList = new List<List<sObject>>();
    List<PrincipalProduit__c> var=new List<PrincipalProduit__c>();
    for(integer l=0;l<mailList.size();l++){
        searchList = [FIND :mailList[l] IN EMAIL FIELDS RETURNING PrincipalProduit__c(id)];   
        var.addAll((List<PrincipalProduit__c>)searchList[0]);
    }
    system.debug(var);
    return var;
}
```

This will return `List<String>`

```
public  List<String> getValo(){
    List<String> mailList=getMail();
    List<List<sObject>> searchList = new List<List<sObject>>();
    List<String> var=new List<String>();
    for(integer l=0;l<mailList.size();l++){
        searchList = [FIND :mailList[l] IN EMAIL FIELDS RETURNING PrincipalProduit__c(id)];   
        for(PrincipalProduit__c principalProd : (List<PrincipalProduit__c>)searchList[0]){
            var.add(principalProd.Id);
        }
    }
    system.debug(var);
    return var;
}
```

Comment: @Ganji :  I used your method and she shows me "Too many SOSL queries: 21"

Comment: You will get that error because you are doing your SOSL in for loop, you will have to change your logic to avoid doing a query in for loop.

Comment: @ Ganji  same erreur

Comment: I think you are getting this error because your mailList.size() is greater than 20, and in each iteration of for loop you are executing SOSL query. Maximum number of SOSL query in a single transaction can be 20. You need to separate the transactions here using batch apex . Execute it with the batch size of 20 or less.

Comment: @Manish A i don't think beacause in my object, i have that seven données

Comment: @corentinKOUNOU Updated the answer, the optimized version should work for you.

Comment: I used "debug (principalProd.id)" and I see all my id.
I think my problem comes from visualForce 
To display the id, that's what I did: 
 <apex:pageBlock >
               <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!valo}" var="val">
                   <apex:column value="{!val}"/>
               </apex:pageBlockTable>  
        </apex:pageBlock>

Comment: @corentinKOUNOU Yup, so I guess that solves your problem. You just need to add required fields to your query and you can display it in visual force page.

Comment: Than you for your help @Ganji

Comment: @corentinKOUNOU Glad to help you - Vijay

Answer (score 0):

SOSL returns list of list of Sobject (Two-Dimensional array) searchlist should be

```
List<List<Sobject>> searchlist = new List<List<Sobject>> ();
```

and var should be

```
List<PrincipalProduit__c> var = new List<PrincipalProduit__c> ();
```

Answer (score 0):

SOSL queries return a list of lists of SObject (List<List<SObject>>). Additionally, if you want to dynamically generate the search fields you will need to use dynamic SOSL like:

```
String query = 'FIND \'' + String.join(mailListWithQuotesEscaped, '\',\'') + '\' IN EMAIL FIELDS RETURNING ' + buildListOfFields();
List<List<SObject>> searchList = Search.query(query);
```

My final point; you should avoid performing any form of query in a for loop. Try to bulkify the query so you build a single query then process the returned values to split the data back up again.

Take a look at the SOSL documentation, including the [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_database/apex_database_sosl), [handling the results](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_working_with_results.htm), the [dynamic SOSL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_sosl.htm) stuff and the [reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_syntax.htm).

Comment: I have an error "unexpected token: 'FINDeasyfit.vlg'" after trying your method

Comment: I forgot to show adding the quotes. I have updated.